# Accessing an Object value with a variable key Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, socket.io

I am working with a MongoDB document that has many key-value pairs. I want to update the values using `findOneAndUpdate` but in order to do that, I need the key names. My keys are all associated with a long form on the front end, so I am hoping to save some time and pass the keys back as a variable called 'trait' using socket.io, and then use that key in my `findOneAndUpdate`.

```
    socket.on('editchar', ({ id, trait, val }, callback) => {
        // console.log(id, trait, val);
        Character.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': id}, { trait : val })
            char.save()
        })
    })
```

The problem is that my `findOneAndUpdate` thinks my `trait` variable is the key "trait". Anyone know how I can get around this, and have my `findOneAndUpdate` take my variable as a key?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

let me show an example about object and keys

```js
var key = "name";

var person = {
    [key]: "Halil",
    age: 29,
};

console.log(person);
// { name: 'Halil', age: 29 }
```

If you look example, it's gonna console you that object so it's using `[key]: "Halil"` meaning that key is gonna be `name`. In this context I believe what you need to do is this:

```js
socket.on('editchar', ({ id, trait, val }, callback) => {
    // console.log(id, trait, val);
    Character.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': id }, { [trait]: val })
    char.save()
});
```

with doing `[trait]: val` you are telling it's a propery name not the property itself :)